# splitting strings with operator relative to parentheses

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want the following strings to be split by the (relative to the pairs of parentheses) outer-most operator (in this case: '+'):

```
1: "((20 + 20) + a)"
2: "(20 + ((20 + 20) + 20))
```

The results should be like this:

```
1: "((20 + 20) "         and           " a)"
2: "(20 "                and           " ((20 + 20) + 20))"
```

Comment: That'll be £50 please. Seriously, what have you tried?

Comment: You can't do this with regex.

Comment: Okay, that's a pity! :( I'm currently programming a Compiler in which operations are always in paranthesis. Is there another way to go with regex and nested operations?

Comment: Why not loop through the characters of your String, marking indexes with operators, then after you reach the end of the string, you know where the last operator is and can split the string accordingly.

Comment: @Kon even simpler. walk the string, keep a depth counter which you increase on `(` and decrease on `)` (initialised to `0`). `if (currentChar == "+" && depth == 1) { //split here }`

Comment: What about `(1 + (2 + 3) + 4)`? How do you break ties?

Comment: @Bohemian Presumably he would want to perform two splits there.

Comment: adding to @m.buettner's idea, have you looked into using a stack? This is one way to solve this type of problem. http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/5.STACKS-AND-QUEUES.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with regex, but you can try something like this:

```
// locations of top-level operators:
List<Integer> locations = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int level = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);

    if (c == '(') {
        level++;
    }
    else if (c == ')') {
        level--;
    } 
    else if ("+-*/".indexOf(c) >= 0 && level == 1) {
        locations.add(i);
    }
}
```

You can then "split" your string with `substring()` and whatever is in `locations`.

---

If you *always* want to split on the outermost operator (e.g. split on `+` in `(((a + 1)))`), then things get a little more tricky, but your overall approach doesn't have to change drastically. One idea that comes to mind is to build a `Map<OperatorData, Integer>` (where `OperatorData` is a class containing the operator token (e.g. `+`) and an int representing how far it's nested) that maps to locations in the string. `OperatorData` can be `Comparable` based on the nest level.

`OperatorData` might look something like this:

```
class OperatorData implements Comparable<OperatorData> {
    private String token;
    private int level;

    // constructor etc.

    @Override
    public int compareTo(OperatorData other) {
        return Integer.compare(level, other.level);
    }
}
```

You can then go through this map and split on the operators that have the lowest nest level. The approach might look something like this:

```
// location of top-level operators:
Map<OperatorData, Integer> operators = new HashMap<>();

int level = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < str.length()) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);

    if (c == '(') {
        level++;
    } else if (c == ')') {
        level--;
    } else if (isOperatorChar(c)) {
        final int index = i;
        StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();
        token.append(c);

        while (isOperatorChar(c = str.charAt(i + 1))) {
            token.append(c);
            i++;
        }

        operators.put(new OperatorData(token.toString(), level), index);
    }

    i++;
}

// find smallest OperatorData in map
```

Comment: what about (((a + 1)))

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia What about it? This should work as expected: nothing will be added to `locations`.

Comment: But operands can be either literals, variableNames or operations. How about this? How can I read them out?

Comment: @GunterGribs You can use the exact same approach. In the last `else if`, advance the loop control variable `i` until the character you're on is a space or bracket (meaning you have gone past the variable name/operation token). If you're doing something like this, you may want to 1) use a `while`-loop and 2) keep track of *both* start/end positions of the top-level non-bracket tokens.

Comment: @Downvoter Kindly leave a comment.

Comment: The last else if will execute for digits and letters, which do not count as operators based on the problem statement.

Comment: Also I believe Kevin has a point about `(((a + 1)))` as the original problem statement was to split on the "outest" operator. In this case, the + sign would be the least nested operator.

Comment: @Brigham Yes, perhaps you're right. I might have interpreted the question incorrectly. See the edit (again).